# ssh are not enabled in cpanel

Tags: ssh, hosting, cpanel

I am running hosting company. At first when i create any user then all the user get ssh access and ssl certificate, because i had enable ssh during package creation.

I was developing web programming which will enable the account from my own website "http://freewingsofficial.com/hosting_for_nepali". There I mistakenly activate ssh in user too.
Now all the user are not getting any ssh access.
Any help is most appreciable. thank you in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Basically you should not provide ssh access to user users, especially on a cPanel server.

Comment: if i create other cpanel then ssh is disabled when created.

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit that specific package in WHM and see if ssh is enabled or not.  `WHM -> Packages -> Edit a Package`. Select the package that coresponds to the hosting package from your website. There should be a check mark with '**Shell Access**' on the Option section of your WHM package. You should enabled that so the new created accounts with that package can have ssh access.

Comment: bogdan sir, i have enabled ssh from packages but ssh is not enabled sir,
i have edited all packages but also ssh was not enabled so i deleted all package and created new packages but also same problem.

Comment: Is that happening when you create a new package from WHM or when someone orders it on your website?

Comment: both,
when i create package from whm panel or create order from frontend guest

Comment: It's hard to say really... I do not have such an issue on my cpanel server. Try creating a new package from WHM and be sure that shell access is checked then from WHM create a new account using that package and see if that works. Also check if you have any firewall which blocks your ssh requests